# Retrieving reviews from the Google Places API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I know that the Google Places API will allow you to search for a business and return a reference ID for that business.  Once I have that reference ID, I can make a call to the place details page that returns some information.

Part of this information includes some reviews.  The problem with the reviews is that:

- Only 5 are returned.
- They're curated by Google.

How does a developer use the Google APIs to pull ALL of the reviews that appear in Google for a company?

Comment: My need is also same. Can anybody from Google Team please respond to this question?

Comment: Actually, this is one of the most popular feature requests in public issue tracker of Maps APIs. Have a look and star the [issue 7630](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7630).